# Can $\beta$, $\mu$ or $p$ or other intensive variables be expressed as expectation values in every ensemble?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

If I compare for example the canonical ensemble with partition function $\tilde{Z}_{\beta}$ and the microcanonical ensemble with partition function $E_{\beta}$, $\beta$ and $E$ seem to be  some "kind of" paired variables:

- They appear as a pairing in the exponential factor $e^{\beta H}$ in the canonical distribution.
- $\partial_{\beta} - \ln\tilde{Z}_{\beta}= <H> = E$, and in a similar way $\partial_E - \ln Z_E = \beta$ (of course the symbols here are to see in their respective ensembles).
- In this way of calculating $E$ and $\beta$, since $E$ is just the expectation value of an observable $H$ on the phase space, it would be completely "symmetric" if the same applied for $\beta$ as well.

I can spot the same pairing property for $V$ and $\beta p$, or $N$ and $\beta \mu$.

However: $E$ isn't only a parameter, but it's also always either an expectation value of a function of the microstate, or it the sharply peaked value of that function. $\beta$ on the other hand is nothing but a parameter - or is it?

Hence the question: Can I express those quantities like $\beta$ as expectation values / sharply peaked values of a function of the microstate as well? If so, does it only work for certain ensembles / systems, or all of them? And is there some kind of framework that explains this pairing?

To give an example of the direction I'm looking for:
I know for example that there is something called "instantaneous temperature", which is the kinetic energy of the particles, divided by the degrees of freedom. However, I have seen this definition only for ideal gasses, and it is not clear to me wether that applies to the canonical ensemble as well.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical ensemble is also commonly called the $NVT$ ensemble, meaning $N, V, T$ are constant and together are able to pin down all thermodynamic properties of the system. All other quantities are either directly related ($\beta=\frac{1}{k_bT}$ as a trivial example) or can be extracted from the partition function ($p,\mu$, etc). The ones that are extracted from the partition function are typically only defined through expectation values: the real value would fluctuate but in the macroscopic limit it will only take on one value. So can you express $\beta$ as a sharply peaked value? In the canonical ensemble $T$ is fixed so $\beta$ is fixed as well.

Are $\beta, E$ conjugated variables? The answer is no. The reason that $\beta, E$ appear together often is that together they form a unitless quantity since $\beta$ has units (energy)$^{-1}$. Only unitless quantities can be used in expressions like $e^x$ and they can be convenient to work with.

To find conjugated variables just look at one of the [thermodynamic potentials and its corresponding fundamental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equations#Thermodynamic_potentials). For example for $F(N,V,T)$:
$$dF=-SdT-pdV+\mu dN$$
The conjugated variables are any variables that appear together so $S\leftrightarrow T,p\leftrightarrow V$ and $\mu \leftrightarrow N$. Note that $V$ is conjugated to $p$ and not $\beta p$, which is just another common way to <del>make $p$ unitless</del> to give $p$ certain units.

And sorry but I don't know anything about instantaneous temperature but I hope this clarified things at least a little bit.

Comment: The facts stated are already known to me, and I put the word "conjugated" in quotation marks so it doesn't get confused with the canonical meaning. To make it more clear I removed the word and the tag "conjugation". 
"In the canonical ensemble T is fixed so β is fixed as well" - This may be the core of the question: When we fix $E$ in the microcanonical ensemble, what we do is we fix $H(x,p)$, a function on phase space. 
Do you mean the same, when you say, you "fix" T? You probably meant it just to be a parameter, that is choosen. I'm asking if there is a function that you can fix?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Ok I wasn't sure what you were confused about so I tried to state everything as explicit as possible. So what do I mean with 'fix'? I can give a more practical example. Right now I'm working on Monte Carlo simulations which can simulate particle systems. I use both the $NPT$ and the $NVT$ ensemble. In the $NPT$ ensemble $N,P,T$ are the input I give to the system and they are 'fixed'. In this case the volume is something I must extract from my system (for $NPT$ this is really easy though). My system is very small so $V$ oscillates by quite a lot.

Comment: Let's say you simulate a particle system in the N V E Ensemble (microcanonical), and let's say you want to extract T from your system. What is the exact procedure of this "extraction"? Would the T that you get from this extraction oscillate as well? And if you'd apply the same extraction scheme to your N,V,T ensemble, would it then not oscillate anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would calculate $T$ in $NVE$. I found this paper http://fge.if.usp.br/~oliveira/PRE_68_066125_2003.pdf where they do it in section IV but to understand it you would have to read the entire paper. I suspect $T$ would oscillate or at least have some uncertainty. In the $NVT$ ensemble you can't extract $T$,  it is an input parameter and you have to define it before you can even simulate your system.

Comment: It is clear that in the NVT ensemble T is an imput parameter. Yet, I could do the same calculation that I did for the NVE Ensemble, but applied to data from the NVT Ensemble. What i'd get is a value again. Would this value yield T (the input parameter) again? Would it have an uncertainty? (As an analogy, I can sum up all the energies of the particles in the NVE Ensemble, and would retrieve E, the energy I simulated the NVE-Ensemble with). 

My initial question is wether there is a theoretical framework for this kind of calculation that yields T, and wether this extends to any ensemble,